# Remove standard Gmap overlays (for parks, landmarks, etc)

Tags: android, iphone, html, mobile, google-maps-api-3

I am making a mobile HTML5 app that uses geolocation and gmaps api to display places of interest around the user's location.

Loading a google map loads a lot of extraneous stuff. I of course dont mind having google's name and the controls, but the parks, landmarks, and other things that it displays as markers mess with the interface because there are lots of markers generated by this app. i cant control the behavior of clicking on one of these 'standard' markers.

**Can i have nothing on the map except my own markers, and if so, how?**

Comment: I think i know your problem and solution, may be you should post your code. Also try learning more about the reference obtained from google maps api